# How can i format the NumPr when i read

Tags: java, docx, docx4j

when i use docx4j read a docx file

i want get the number of a list just like :

1. something
2. other

i can got the text "**something**" but i can't got the "**1.**"

```
P p = (P) o;
PPr ppr = p.getPPr();
NumPr npr = ppr.getNumPr();
if(npr!=null){
    //how to parse npr...
}
List<Object> pl = p.getContent();
for (Object po : pl) {
    dealWithContent(po);
}
```

any one can tell me how to parse it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking is done by docx4j's HTML and PDF output.

Have a look at org.docx4j.model.listnumbering.Emulator, specifically its getNumber method

The emulator maintains internal counters for each list; if you invoke it for each paragraph in document order, then at any point in the document, the counters will reflect the current number of each list.